# How can I strengthen a family of constraints in the presence of a clique constraint?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling

Suppose $x_i$ are binary variables, $y_j$ are arbitrary variables, $a_j$ and $b$ are constants, and I have the following linear constraints:
\begin{align}
x_i + \sum_j a_j y_j &\le b &&\text{for all $i$} \tag1\\
\sum_i x_i &\le 1 \tag2
\end{align}
How can I replace $(1)$ with $(3)$?
\begin{align}
\sum_i x_i + \sum_j a_j y_j &\le b \tag{3}\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider the only two possible cases:

- If $x_i=0$ for all $i$, then $(1)$ and $(3)$ both reduce to $\sum_j a_j y_j \le b$.
- If $x_i=1$ for some $i$, then $(2)$ implies that $x_k=0$ for all other $k \not= i$, and $(1)$ and $(3)$ both reduce to $1+\sum_j a_j y_j \le b$.

---

Alternatively, you can think of lifting $x_i+\sum_j a_j y_j \le b$ to $\alpha_k x_k + x_i+\sum_j a_j y_j \le b$ for some $k \not= i$.  If $x_k=0$, then $\alpha_k$ can be anything.  If $x_k=1$, then $x_i=0$ by $(2)$ and you want to find the largest $\alpha_k$ such that $\alpha_k+\sum_j a_j y_j \le b$ is valid.  Constraint $(1)$ implies that you should take $\alpha_k=1$, yielding $x_k + x_i+\sum_j a_j y_j \le b$.  Now repeat this argument to obtain $(3)$.