# Modelling stronger binary expression

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling

$\delta_1, \delta_2, ..., \delta_k, W$  are binary variables and the constraint $δ_1 + δ_2 + \ldots + δ_k ≤ W$ holds.

Is it better to write $$\delta_1 + \delta_2 + \ldots +\delta_k \leq W$$ or \begin{gathered}
\delta_1 \leq W \\
\delta_2 \leq W \\
...\\
\delta_k \leq W \\ 
\end{gathered}

and why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since $W$ is a binary variable, it follows that
$$
\sum_k \delta_k \le W \le 1
$$
And so you are in the presence of a clique constraint.

@RobPratt [shows](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/6187/how-can-i-strengthen-a-family-of-constraints-in-the-presence-of-a-clique-constra) how to strengthen the second group of constraints in this case, yielding the first constraint.

A simple example : take $\delta_k = 0.9$ for every $k$. It is easy to see that such a solution is valid with the second group, but not with the first one. So the first one leads to a tighter relaxation.