# How to find the index of the item, the first time appears?

Tags: linear-programming, modeling, integer-programming, convex-optimization, big-m

How to formulate this problem as MIP:

For example, we have the following vector of binary variables:
$$
x= [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
$$
How to find out when the first "1" is recorded? For example, the index of the first "1" is 4. How to let the solver return for example, $y =[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0].$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a formulation if at least one $x_i$ must be $1$:
\begin{align}
\sum_i y_i &= 1 \tag1\label1\\
y_i &\le x_i &&\text{for all $i$} \tag2\label2\\
y_i &\le 1-x_j &&\text{for $j<i$} \tag3\label3
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} selects exactly one $y_i$ to be $1$.
Constraint \eqref{2} enforces the implication $y_i \implies x_i$.
Constraint \eqref{3} enforces the implication $y_i \implies \lnot x_j$.

If instead it is possible that $x_i=0$ for all $i$, relax \eqref{1} to $\le 1$ and impose
\begin{align}
y_i &\ge x_i - \sum_{j<i} x_j &&\text{for all $i$} \tag4
\end{align}

In either case, you can use \eqref{1} to strengthen \eqref{3} as follows:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i>j} y_i &\le 1-x_j &&\text{for all $j$} \tag5
\end{align}

See [How can I strengthen a family of constraints in the presence of a clique constraint?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/6187/how-can-i-strengthen-a-family-of-constraints-in-the-presence-of-a-clique-constra)

---

For the general case where $x \equiv 0$ is feasible, [PORTA](https://porta.zib.de/) yields the following formulation:
\begin{align}
\sum_i y_i &\le 1 \\
y_i &\le x_i &&\text{for all $i$} \\
x_i &\le \sum_{j \le i} y_j &&\text{for all $i$}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much. Constraints 1-3 solve the problem. Yes, it is possible that $xi=0$ for all  $i$. In that case, I believe you mean replacing constraint 1 with constraint 4 and constraint 3 with constraint 5. I mean, solve the problem with constraints 2, 4, and 5. That also solves the problem in less computation time since it reduces the number of constraints! I am wondering what you mean by " strengthen." Do you mean reducing the number of constraints?

Comment: If you impose $(2)$, $(4)$, and $(5)$, you can omit $(1)$, which is dominated by $(5)$, and you end up with the second formulation by @xdy.  By *strengthen*, I mean that the LP feasible region is smaller, cutting off more fractional solutions.

Comment: Thank you! @ RobPartt. The PORTA  formulation you suggested might be the best as it requires fewer constraints than all other formulations.

Comment: More importantly, the PORTA formulation yields the integer hull, so there are no fractional extreme points.

Answer (score 7):

Suppose the index is 1-based and set constant $u_0 = 0$. With binary variables $u_i, y_i, i=1,\dots,n$ and constraints
$$
\begin{align}
u_i &\geq x_i\\
u_i &\geq u_{i-1}\\
u_i &\leq x_i + u_{i-1}\\
y_i &\leq u_i\\
y_i &\leq 1 - u_{i-1}\\
y_i &\geq u_i - u_{i-1}
\end{align}
$$
$y_i$ indicate the first $x$.

In logic expressions:
$$
u_i = x_i \vee u_{i-1}\\
y_i = u_i \wedge \neg u_{i-1}
$$

It is just my first thought and I have no idea if it is efficient.

---

Second formulation:
$$
y_i \leq x_i\\
y_i \geq x_i - \sum_{i' < i} x_{i'}\\
y_i \leq 1 - \sum_{i' < i} y_{i'}
$$

Comment: +1.  We had similar ideas for your second formulation.  I suspect that your first formulation will scale better, with only $O(n)$ constraints, each of which is sparse.

Comment: Thanks! Both formulations work. As @ RobPratt mentioned, the second formulation is expected to be better as it has less number of constraints and binary variables.

Comment: Yes but I just found the last constraint in the second formulation is stupid and could be replaced by $\sum y_i \leq 1$...

Comment: Thanks, @ xd y. It could be replaced, but both solve the problem.
Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

If number is non-binary, say non negative continuous number $c$, introduce a vector of binary $y_i$ initialized to 0.
Have two binary variables $z_1 \ and z_2$

$c - x_i \le My_{i}$
$x_i - c \le M(1-y_{i})$
$\sum_{j \lt i} y_j \le i \quad \forall i \in\ N$
$y_{i+1}\le y_i \ \forall i \in\ N$: this ensures y turns 0 once c=x and remains 0 for rest of the array.

First index will be $\sum_{j \lt i} y_j$

Comment: Thanks! Sutanu. 
I believe that your first two constraints contradict each other.

Comment: if $c-x_i > 0$ then $y_i$ has to be 1, then $x_i-c <0, y_i$ is free to be 1. Vice-versa, in other words if $c \neq x_i$ y is 1. When $c=x_i$ then possible $y_i = 0$, that will be forced by last constraint.

Comment: The following is not working:
```
import numpy as np
m=gp.Model()
cost=[-70,-60,-50,-40,-30,-20,-10,0]
cost=np.flipud(cost)
x=[1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0]
x=np.flipud(x)
# x=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
M=10
C=1
B=m.addVars(len(x), vtype=GRB.BINARY)
obj=gp.quicksum(cost[i]*B[i] for i in range (len(x)))
m.setObjective(obj)



    
m.addConstrs(M*B[i]>=C-x[i] for i in range(len(x)))
m.addConstrs(M*B[i]>=x[i]-C for i in range(len(x)))
    

for i in range(len(x)): 
    j=i-1

    m.addConstr(gp.quicksum(B[jj] for jj in range (j))<=i)
    
m.optimize()
```

Comment: Let me get back to you.

Comment: Obj should be =gp.quicksum(B[i] for i in range (len(x))) or simple B.sum(). Also you are trying to determine first index for C=1 in the array, x. I don't think 1 is there in the array. I have added one more constraint B[i+1]<=B[i] for i in range(len(x))-1

Comment: Thanks. For "I don't think 1 is there in the array". 1 is in the array, the array is x.  x=[1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0].
"Also you are trying to determine first index for C=1 in the array, x?" yes.

Comment: Ok my bad, I thought you are comparing with cost.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort to help. I do appreciate your time!