How to track the first timestep at which a binary variable becomes 1 in an IP?
I have an MIP where I have a binary variable $y_t$ which is set to 1 or 0 and is indexed by time t. It can be set to 1 at multiple timestamps but it is never continuously 1 for more than single timestamp. It can; however, be continuously zero. What I would like to do is to track the very first time that y becomes 1 and the very last time that y becomes 1. An example is shown in the table below. What am I struggling to do is to track the first timestamp at which y becomes 1.
My current attempt is to create two more binary variables $v^1_t$ and $v^2_t$ which should be 1 at the first and last occurrence of $y_t = 1$, respectively.
I can set $v^2_t$ correctly using the following constraint:
$$t \cdot v^2_t \geq t \cdot y_t - \sum^{T}_{t'=t+1}{t' \cdot u_t'} \quad \forall t \in T$$
This table shows what the correct behaviour should be.



t
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10




y
0
1
0
0
0
0
1
0
1
0


v1
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


v2
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0



Is anyone able to provide some guidance on how to formulate constraints to set the $v^1_t$ correctly? I have also tried setting $v^1$ and $v^2$ as continuous variables but I have come up against the same issue in that I can set $v^2$ correctly but not $v^1$.

My idea was to restrict both two variables in different constraints.
First two constraint is to ensure AT MOST 1 variable can turn on to 1.
Next, if $y_t$ is zero, then corresponding variable $v^1_t$ and $v^2_t$ should be zero.
Last constraint is forward and backward to turn on variable.
Finally, since I thought the third constraints cannot enforce the value perfectly, I use objective function to guide the search the optimal solution.
To indicate the first binary variable as 1:
$\sum_{t}v^1_t \le 1$
$\sum_ty_t \le \sum_t v^1_t \cdot |T|$
$y_t \ge v^1_t,  \forall t \in T$
$\sum^{t'=t}_{t'=1} y_{t'} \ge \sum^{t'=t}_{t'=1}v^1_{t'} \forall t \in T$
To indicate the last binary variable as 1:
$\sum_{t}v^2_t \le 1$
$\sum_ty_t \le \sum_t v^2_t \cdot |T|$
$y_t \ge v^2_t,  \forall t \in T$
$\sum^{t'=|T|}_{t'=t} y_{t'} \ge \sum^{t'=|T|}_{t'=t}v^2_{t'} \forall t \in T$
Combine with the objective function as following to enforce the index should be minimum and maximum in $v^1_t$ and $v^2_t$:
$\min \sum_t (tv^1_t - tv^2_t)$

Would that still work if $y_t$ is continuously zero? I like the approach

Concerning $v_t^1$, I think you would then need to reformulate the first constraint with a $\leq$ and you can add a constraint that assures that $v^1_t$ must be 1 in case there is at least on $y_t$ that is greater zero, e.g. with  $\sum^{T}{t=1}y_t \leq \sum^{T}{t=1}v^1_{t} \cdot |T| $

@PeterD oh, thanks! I missed the $y_t$ would be continuously zero. I have modified my answer and add your suggesstion.

Also, I think $v^2_t$ should be the same as $v^1_t$.

Won't the constraint $y_t \ge \sum^{t'=t}{t'=1}v^1{t'} \forall t \in T$ force $y_t$ to stay at value 1 in all time periods after the first time it takes value 1?

@prubin I got your point, I'm going to fix it. thanks.

@prubin I think the way to correct the formulation is to modify as $\sum_t y_t \ge \sum^{t'=t}_{t'=1}v^1_t \forall t \in T$.

Suppose that we set $y_1 = 1 = y_3$ and $v^1_3 = 1,$ which is incorrect. That seems to satisfy your replacement constraint.

Yes, so there is a reason I put the objective function to guide the search.

Thank you for your answer ytsao. I have tested it and it seems to work well for me; however, I have decided to implement the first formulation by xy d in this question https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/9440/how-to-find-the-index-of-the-item-the-first-time-appears
